# Setting up custom Shipping method based on Weight & Distance

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, shipping-methods

I have been developing on the Magento platform for quite some time but have now come to the part of actually getting everything setup to go live!

I am very confused about how to setup custom shipping methods in Magento since we will be using three different carriers - **Royal Mail, DPD/Interlink and FastWay(Ireland)**. Also, I am not at all sure where and how to add tracking numbers to the invoices for customers..?

I would like to setup the shipping methods based on parcel weight & destination but for products that ship to Ireland I need to send them using FastWay only. In addition, if orders are placed before 2pm they will be shipped the same day but I am not sure how to setup any of these rules and I have found myself looking and dozens and dozens of extensions but none seem to offer a solution. I'm going round and round in circles!

**I have already implemented an ERP solution to handle order processing in the backend but how do I setup any custom shipping methods for the frontend?**

I am also using MetaPack to print shipping lables.

I would be interested to know if anyone else has struggled with any of the above to please lend me some friendly advice on how to get past this issue...

Answer (score 1):

I've realised it really is quite simple to do! I've used Table rates and added the custom variables to the CSV file then uploaded it. Delivery cost is calculated by weight v destination and all is fine. Next, I will create a custom module Called Fastway as my shipping method and hopefully that is done.

Lastly I need to add the tracking numbers!

Comment: Remember you can mark your own question as solved if you've solved it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with the tracking number part, you've solved the rest yourself.  Once the order is placed it will be accessible in Sales->Orders. When it is ready for despatch the client would hit the Ship button (Deliver if you've used the Uk language pack).

There is then a section with an Add Tracking Number button that, when pressed allows you to add a tracking number and description;

[image]

Depending on how you've done your transactional emails, this would normally be added to the shipping/delivery email sent to the customer so they can track it and they don't annoy you with phone calls about where their purchase is.